# travis-ci script

Tags: php, github, integration, phing, travis-ci

I'm trying to setup phing to work with travis-ci, but I can't get it to run a setup script to get all the dependencies installed.

My .travis.yml file is:

```
language: php
php:
  - 5.2
script: ./.travis-phing.sh
```

In travis, I get the error:

```
/home/travis/build.sh: line 105: ./.travis-phing.sh: Permission denied
```

What is causing that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Solved**

The script to be set to execute. I used:

```
chmod a+x .travis-phing.sh
```

Then simply commit, and push back to github.

Comment: The travis docs suggest `chmod ugo+x` rather than `a+x`.   (No idea if there are cases where this matters!)

Comment: No; `a` is just a shorthand for `ugo`.

Answer (score 1):

## Run the script using bash

**Another option would be to run the script using bash**, this would omit the need to modify the files' permissions.

```
bash path/to/file.sh
```

Alternatively:

```
sh path/to/file.sh
```

---

### *Note that*

In this case you're **not** *executing* the script itself, you're *executing* `bash` or `sh` which then *runs* the script. Therefore the script does not need to be *executable*.

Make sense?

---

I've found this solution incredibly useful myself. I'm mainly running `node` & `npm` projects on travis-ci, those builds make use of the `npm test` command which you can configure to be anything.

I'm order to modify file permission I need to use `sudo chmod ...` on my local machine. But you can't always use `sudo` on travis-ci.

`sh file.sh` allows me to run my tests both locally and on travis-ci without having to manually update permissions.